# How do I get the output path for a CMake project?

Tags: cmake

I'd like to specify a post-build action that copies files to the build output directory.

`${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}` appears to be empty.

How can I determine the output path for my generated project in my CMakeLists.txt file?

Answer (score 3):

A *project* has no "output". A runtime *target* has a "output". The "output" here should be understood as binary/executable resulting from the compilation.

`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` initializes the `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property of a runtime *target*.

In case the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` is empty, then the target will output it's executable in `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`. So you can check if `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` is empty, if it is, use `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`.